# Getting MyPy Working in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, flycheck

I'm struggling to get type checking working in spacemacs, and I would appreciate any help. I've installed MyPy properly on my system (I can run it from terminal) and added `python-mypy` to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`, and if I run `flycheck-verify-setup` (`M-m e v`) `python-mypy` is listed there with the correct path to the executable (it's not disabled either). However, I still don't get an error even if running mypy from the terminal does produce an "incompatible type" error.

Any hints as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else struggles with this, simply doing `pip install flake8-mypy` did the trick for me.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick in normal emacs for me too!

Comment: For support for plain `mypy` integration look [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7568).

Comment: I added `python-mypy` to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` but got `Package python-mypy is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?`

Answer (score 0):

I added `flycheck-mypy` to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages
'(
  flycheck-mypy
  )
```

and enabled it in `user-config` (`python-flake8` is required)

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (require 'flycheck-mypy)
  (flycheck-add-next-checker 'python-flake8 'python-mypy t)
```